# A text-to-speech app for Android (read aloud from Google Docs)

Tags: android, google-apps, speech-synthesis, google-drive

I have a Samsung Galaxy Core LTE G386W running Android 4.4.2. Using Google Drive I have a Google Doc open. How can I have the text read out loud to me, say while I am walking. Can you suggest an app? By the way, this is apparently built-in to Android, but I can't find instructions or make it work.

I would also like have "read aloud" a PDF file or a web page, but my priority is a Google Doc)

Comment: You've probably mis-interpreted my corresponding comment: Yes, there's a feature called "TalkBack screen reader" – but that's not reading-aloud what's printed there, but rather feedback on what you've touched. So no, it's AFAIK *not* built into Android. // Some [talking PDF readers are in my app lists](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_pdf#group_112) btw. But I'm not aware of such for Google Drive.

Comment: BTW: Did you check out [Google Text-to-Speech](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.tts)? App description sounds as if it would work for every app: *Google Text-to-speech powers applications to read the text on your screen aloud.* Also worth checking: [8 Great Apps to Voice Read Text on iOS and Android](http://www.guidingtech.com/31832/best-apps-voice-reading-text-ios-android/): *NaturalReader lets you listen to ebooks, webpages and PDFs imported for cloud servies like Dropbox, Google Drive or just your local storage*, sounds like what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I built [Intelligent Speaker](https://intelligent-speaker.com) - browser extension. You can add your text on the desktop computer and listen to it through the phone later - we have personal podcast feeds.

[image: Intelligent Speaker]

Answer (score 0):

This app is both on Android and ios. I have been using it for a couple years. You just need to make sure your PDFs or text is OCR (Ocular Character Recognition), that means no kindle locked books.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=voicedream.reader

Answer (score 0):

- Open Google Books (or any other reading app)
- open the text page you'd like to heave read to you
- make a pinch gesture "Zoom out" (make a "V" with pointing finger and middle finger and move them together)
- some menus appear: at the bottom of the page, a progressbar and more importantly at the top right corner a lookingglass icon, an "Aa" icon and a "..." aligned vertically.
- Click/touch the "..."
- Click "Read aloud" (in German it's "Vorlesen")

Then the computer will read the text to you in the language you've specified in the "Text-to-Speech" settings.